# At least 3 students have birthdays in the same month

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations, combinations

There are 30 students in a class .  Is it true that at least 3 students have birthdays in the same month ?

I am able to do it for 2 , but for 3 people i am very confused, Please help me to go through this problem.

Comment: There are 12 months. So you can allocate 2 different students to each month. That deals with 24 students. But any more and you get 3 students in the same month.

Comment: Did you use the pigeonhole principle for 2 students? You need atleast 13 students to guarantee that atleast 2 students have the birthday in the same month. For 3 students to have their birthday in the same month, you need atleast 25 students which is less than 30. Think of the months as pigeonholes and the students as the pigeons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove this by contradiction.

Assume that there is no month in which more than two students have birthdays. Then there are at most $2\times12=24$ students. This contradicts the fact that there are 30 students. Hence, the original assumption is false, so there is a month in which at least three students have birthdays.